# convert javascript file to html entities

Tags: php, javascript, html-entities

Is it possible to convert a *.js file to html entities?

I use this code to convert html files but javascript files won't work. Is it possible?

```
$ch = curl_init($file_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$code = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($code).'</pre>';
```

The users upload files to my server and I don't want users to be able to run the script from my server. It should be just text.
Disallow js files is not an option.

Comment: What you're doing should work. If you're outputting what they upload as per your quoted code, then if they upload a JavaScript file you'll just get a bunch of JavaScript output. If they upload something with `<script>` tags in it, `htmlentities` will escape the `<` and so you'll just get "<script>" and a bunch of JavaScript code. What are you seeing to make you think that people can run script when you're pre-processing things as above?

Comment: the script just outputted a js file so it would be like you are reading a js file and not a php script. But I think i've fixed it now. I set the header to a text/html file so it's not a js file but a html file with som text that looks like js. Dunno if its exacly like I want it but it's a start.

Comment: @amos I just now figured out he's talking about HTML encoding the text rather than actually extracting elements. Sorry. No point leaving that comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hy

You can check if the upload file has the .js extension and apply the "htmlentities()" function.
Then, if the files must be downloaded, when the user download the file, check its extension, if its ".js", apply the html_entity_decode().

Or, you can add a .htaccess file in the folder used for upload, and block external access to ".js" files:

`<files *.js>`

`order allow,deny`

`deny from all`

`</files>`